# Adjusting size of custom dialog box in android

Tags: android

I am building an custom alert dialog box for my application i have written the code and its working but the only problem is its size it is not adjusting according to my content in dialog box. below is my code:

```
public class CustomDialogBoxActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01main);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(CustomDialogBoxActivity.this);
                myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_sms_layout);
                myDialog.setTitle("Select any one");


                Button ok = (Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
                final RadioGroup radioGrp = (RadioGroup)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupSmsDialog);

                final CheckBox mob1 = (CheckBox)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxMob1);
                final CheckBox mob2 = (CheckBox)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxMob2);
                mob1.setText("9029691986");
                mob2.setText("99263911766");

                ok.setOnClickListener(this);

                ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(mob1.isChecked() && mob2.isChecked()) {
                            if(radioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioSms) {
                                String[] phoneArray = {mob1.getText().toString(),mob2.getText().toString()};

                                Log.v("MOB1",mob1.getText().toString());
                                Log.v("MOB2",mob2.getText().toString());
                                Log.v("Mobile No", ""+phoneArray.toString());
                                sendSms("SMS Message",phoneArray);

                            }else if(radioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioBusinessCard) {
                                String[] phoneArray = {mob1.getText().toString(),mob2.getText().toString()};

                                Log.v("MOB1",mob1.getText().toString());
                                Log.v("MOB2",mob2.getText().toString());
                                Log.v("Mobile No", ""+phoneArray.toString());
                                sendSms("SMS Business Card",phoneArray);
                            }
                        }else if(mob1.isChecked() && !mob2.isChecked()) {
                            if(radioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioSms) {
                                String[] phoneArray = {mob1.getText().toString()};

                                Log.v("MOB1",mob1.getText().toString());                                
                                Log.v("Mobile No", ""+phoneArray.toString());
                                sendSms("SMS Message",phoneArray);

                            }else if(radioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioBusinessCard) {
                                String[] phoneArray = {mob1.getText().toString()};

                                Log.v("MOB1",mob1.getText().toString());                                
                                Log.v("Mobile No", ""+phoneArray.toString());
                                sendSms("SMS Business Card",phoneArray);
                            }

                        }else if(!mob1.isChecked() && mob2.isChecked()) {
                            if(radioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioSms) {
                                String[] phoneArray = {mob2.getText().toString()};

                                Log.v("MOB2",mob2.getText().toString());
                                Log.v("Mobile No", ""+phoneArray.toString());
                                sendSms("SMS Message",phoneArray);

                            }else if(radioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioBusinessCard) {
                                String[] phoneArray = {mob2.getText().toString()};

                                Log.v("MOB2",mob2.getText().toString());
                                Log.v("Mobile No", ""+phoneArray.toString());
                                sendSms("SMS Business Card",phoneArray);
                            }

                        }else if(!mob1.isChecked() && !mob2.isChecked()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select atleast one number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }                       
                    }
                });
                myDialog.show();
            }

        });
    }

    public void sendSms(String message,String[] phoneNumber) {

        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
        startActivity(smsIntent);       
    }
}
```

This is the [output](http://i42.tinypic.com/2rw4xw3.png) that i'm getting on button click

This is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is my main activity, from here, I want to display a dialog, 
                        after the user clicked the button below this text." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my dialog_sms_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupSmsDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioSms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="SMS" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBusinessCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Card" />
    </RadioGroup>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxMob1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="Primary" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxMob2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Secondary" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="OK" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to adjust the dialog box size please help. thanks in advance

Comment: @ingsaurabh i have post my main.xml as well as dialog_sms_layout.xml
and also added a link for screen shot

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for your situation, but if you want to set it to full width or something similar, you need to get the current Window for the activity and set it's layout params like so:

```
myDialog.show();
Window window = myDialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

#### *Edit*

`FILL_PARENT` has been deprecated, use instead

```
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: its working but if i run application in landscape mode or in tablet then it will occupy whole screen which will look odd.

Comment: its integer parameters of width and height. Simply use something like window.setLayout(300,300);

Comment: FILL_PARENT has been deprecated now !!

Comment: Use MATCH_PARENT instead

Answer (score 8):

You just need to add is style "Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert" to your dialog like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert);
```

and your dialog is looks like normal alert dialog

Comment: Not exactly what folks asked but works perfectly for me. Tnx.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by removing the title bar with this code

```
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and adding padding to elements in my layout to stretch the Dialog box to my liking.

Comment: Worked perfectly, just wrote it before `setContentView`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Write Feedback"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:numStars="5" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputSearchEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/write_feedback"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:padding="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_feedback_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_stroke"
    android:text="submit"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
   </LinearLayout>

Dialog class :- 

dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_feedback);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: please follow this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 1):

Use Relative_Layout instead of Linear_layout to get full width of Custom Dialog.
I don't know why but it's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Okey I cannot find away to fix this but I find a walk aground:
Create a RelaytiveLayout wrap around your root layout and set the gravity to center like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center">
    
   <YourRootLayoutHere/>

</RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void showdialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_disclaimer);
    dialog.show();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    dialogcb= (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            accepted = dialogcb.isChecked();
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit=prefs.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("show_again",!accepted);
            edit.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```